# Laravel Config Auth missing api on guards

Tags: php, laravel, api

This is located in `config / auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Please take a look at these codes above, codes are missing after I install Laravel

`laravel new projectname`

then I expect this should happen.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

but the api part is gone. Can somebody help? I'm new to Laravel and still exploring its updates.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

please run this command.

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: laravel/ui is deprecated in Laravel 8

Comment: I'm actually planning to use separate ui, and use Laravel for api only.